# Identification of roadbike frame

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

On a magazine i saw a bike with a magnificent frame. I would love to know what model it is. Maybe someone can help me.
[image: Picture of the bike]

Comment: Give us a clue! Which magazine, which country, what date, what was the caption, is there anything else in that issue that helps?

Comment: If it was that easy I wouldn't have asked ;-) It was a newer german magazine. But I don't own it, just took a photo.

Comment: Right away one notes that the logo on the headset is for Specialized.

Comment: It does say Crux on the chainstay too. Despite the quality of picture, its clearly modern cause of the disc brakes =)

Comment: couldn't read that on the chainstay ;-) @Nikolai pointed me to the right model and his link to the right year, this frame is model 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the answer above states, this bike is a Specialized E5 Crux. The one in question has the starburst color scheme. This bike has cyclocross geometry, but in the photo you posted the bike has slicks on instead of typical knobby cyclocross tires.

Simply google specialized crux starburst and plenty of photos will crop up.

[image]

Comment: THAT'S exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Wow. That colour scheme is straight out of the 1980s :-)

Answer (score 6):

Looks a lot like a Specialized Crux cyclo cross bike / frame. There are various versions around.
Here is one in a different colour: 
http://www.rutlandcycling.com/314372/products/2016-specialized-crux-e5-cyclocross-frameset-cyan-pink-yellow.aspx
Has the extra piece in the rear triangle near the left dropout:

[image]

Also:
[image]